# Adding South to Django project, development & production

Tags: django, migration, django-south

Adding South to an existing Django project. I have it installed on both the development machine and the "production" server.

I've done the following on the development machine, then: added South app to settings.py,

```
python manage.py syncdb
python manage.py convert_to_south myproject.myapp
```

then changed some models, then

```
python manage.py schemamigration myproject.myapp --auto
python manage.py migrate myproject.myapp
```

Seems to work so far. What I am now not so sure about is what to do on the production server. Just repeat all these steps manually? Upload modified settings.py, do syncdb, convert_to_south, upload modified models.py, do schemamigration, migrate? Something different? The tutorial [here](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/convertinganapp.html) says something about adding migrations to the version control, so, presumably, they should be uploaded and somehow applied on the production server?

Furthermore, right now I am using sqlite3 on the development machine and mysql on the server - does it make things any different south-wise?

Comment: The bounty of South putting migrations in code that uses the ORM is that it makes them back-end agnostic, so your migrations will work on sqlite, mysql and all databases that have a back-end.

Answer (score 16):

My guide says:

1. Install South on server. `import south` from shell just to make sure you are using the same python env.
2. Add `'south'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`.
3. Upload `settings.py`.
4. Restart server
5. `python manage.py syncdb`.
6. Upload new `app/models.py` and `app/migrations/` dir.
7. Restart server.
8. `python manage.py migrate app --fake 0001`
9. `python manage.py migrate app`

Comment: I think this answers the question better than @AKX. One can make out from the question that is still a bit in the dark about deploying his code to the server. +1 (Once you get enough reputation to edit, you should consider improving original answers, that were close, over composing a new one.)

Comment: To clarify in case it's unclear to anyone who reads this: "restart server" does NOT mean you have to reboot the entire server or virtual machine.  Just bounce the webserver.  If you are using a newer version of ubuntu + apache, for instance, "sudo service apache2 reload" should suffice.

Answer (score 4):

To make sure the south migration table exists,

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

and then

```
python manage.py migrate myproject.myapp --fake 0001
python manage.py migrate myproject.myapp
```

That's what's worked for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

**No need to do this in Django >= 1.7**
i am stuck on this more then 1 hour :)

and at last find 1.7 and more have in build upgrading-from-south

**for more info https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south 

may be this one help you**