# Correct workflow when using south and have development and production django environments synced with mercurial

Tags: django, mercurial, django-south

I want to use south to manage database changes in both development and production using mercurial. However I cannot find out what should I do !

Let's say that I have a project that doesn't use south at all. It is syncded in both production and development with mercurial. Everything is working fine !

Now, one day I want to make a change to a model of the application test. So, what I in my development environment  is

```
1. python manage.py convert_to_south test
2. python manage.py migrate
```

Now I change the model and then

```
3. python manage.py schemamigration test --auto
4. python manage.py migrate
```

Now I commit everything to mercurial

```
5. hg addremove
6. hg commit -m "Converted to south and changed stuff"
7. hg push production
```

Everything seems to work fine in the uat but, I cannot make it work in production :(

So I thought that the correct workflow would be to log into production and apply changes

```
1. hg update
```

and then just migrate the application

```
2. python manage.py migrate
```

But this is not working, I am getting a strange error of "test_table" already exists (for some reason south wants to crate again the table). Also, I read here [Adding South to Django project, development & production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035296/adding-south-to-django-project-development-production) that I should do a python manage.py migrate test --fake 0001 before doing the migration - but this also didn't work (i got an error for a missing table or somthing like that).

So ? What should I do ? What is the correct way to apply migrations to both development and environment ? Should I leave the /migrations/ directory of my applications out of mercurial and run

```
python manage.py convert_to_south test 
and
python manage.py schemamigration test --auto
```

to both development and production ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`convert_to_south` is just two commands chained together: `schemamigration --init` + `migrate --fake`. So `init` just creates a migration as usual, and `fake` makes sure you don't need to apply migration manually. But your server gets a migration, not creates it, so you really need to run `manage.py migrate test 0001 --fake` and it should be working. Possibly, you haven't run `syncdb` after installing `south` so server DB does not have `south` tables.

So, run:

```
manage.py syncdb
manage.py migrate test 0001 --fake
```

Comment: It works, thanks ! Also, to make a migration on an application that has already been converted to south, the workflow is: in the development "1. change model, 2. python manage.py schemamigration test --auto, 3. python manage.py test migrate... and then in production after pulling the changes: 1. python manage.py test migrate!

Comment: Actually, `python manage.py migrate test`. `Migrate` is the command and `test` is the subject.