# Trouble adding Django Admin system to existing Django application that has South installed

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have an existing Django 1.6 application that is using South.

I now need to add the Django admin application to the existing Django app. After adding the relevant admin entries into INSTALLED_APPS when I run syncdb the following error is shown:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, u"Table
>   'databasename.auth_permission' doesn't exist")

Removing South from the list of installed apps allows syncdb to successfully create the tables.

Is there any way to avoid removing south from the installed apps list just to install the Django Admin tables?

Admin was added by editing settings.py

```
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'THE ORIGINAL APPS ARE HERE',
'south',
```

The trackback is:

```
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 92, in handle_noargs
    syncdb.Command().execute(**options)
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 112, in handle_noargs
    emit_post_sync_signal(created_models, verbosity, interactive, db)
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 216, in emit_post_sync_signal
    interactive=interactive, db=db)
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 185, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 93, in create_permissions
    "content_type", "codename"
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 96, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 857, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1071, in iterator
    for row in self.query.get_compiler(self.db).results_iter():
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 713, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 786, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 124, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 102, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 202, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 734, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 845, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1048, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 826, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 373, in check_error
    raise_mysql_exception(self.__data)
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 117, in raise_mysql_exception
    _check_mysql_exception(errinfo)
  File "path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 110, in _check_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno,errorvalue)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, u"Table 'databasename.auth_permission' doesn't exist")
```

Comment: If you have existing project, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035296/adding-south-to-django-project-development-production

Comment: thanks, but that seems to be about adding south to an existing app, I want to add Django Admin to an existing app that is already using south. I'll take a look anyway, tnx

Comment: Hmm, then did the model change? Or you are just adding admin? There's no reason for admin to fail if you already had the model and data.

Comment: I'm just adding admin. It works fine without south, but with it it fails.

Comment: Can you edit your question to share the code of how you added admin?

Comment: done, but it 's the standard way as per tutorials.

Comment: Can you show the full traceback. What is your full `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?

Comment: Ah that's what you mean "add admin", I thought you were adding admins for individual models. I'm not sure, maybe traceback would help.

Comment: @Alasdair it includes some custom apps then finally south. I can't show the list I'm afraid. If I delete those apps then try to sync, the same result occurs so I don't think it's related to those.

Comment: What about the full traceback? Are the django.contrib apps at the top of `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: yes, I've added the django.contrib apps at the top of the installed apps list.

Comment: What version of South are you using? You can use `pip freeze` to check.

Comment: it's south 0.8.4 - I'll try with the latest, good point.

Comment: it's the same with the latest

Comment: in the end it seemed that because an existing app or db table include the name auth that was the root cause.